# Oracle 11g and Collect Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using ORACLE 11g DB, through a SQL Dev tool.
Unable to use the Collect function with a 'Distinct' clause. When used in my procedure, it's not recognising!

My Query for reference:

```
SELECT nvl(spicd.company_code, '') companycode
     , nvl(scc.company_description, '') companydesc
     , nvl(spicd.plant_code, '') plantcode
     , CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT svh.haulier_code) AS varchar2_ntt) hauliercode
     , CAST(COLLECT(DISTINCT sh.hauier_name) AS varchar2_ntt) hauliername
  FROM saistb_company_code         scc
     , saistb_pve_indv_contact_det spicd

  LEFT OUTER JOIN saistb_vendor_haulier svh
    ON svh.company_code = spicd.company_code
   AND svh.plant_code = spicd.plant_code
   AND svh.vendor_code = spicd.vendor_code

  LEFT OUTER JOIN saistb_haulier sh
    ON sh.haulier_code = svh.haulier_code

 WHERE scc.company_code = spicd.company_code
   AND spicd.company_code LIKE <<companycode>>
   AND spicd.plant_code LIKE <<plantcode>>

 GROUP BY nvl(spicd.company_code, '')
        , nvl(scc.company_description, '')
        , nvl(spicd.plant_code, '')
```

Here `varchar2_ntt` is:

```
create or replace TYPE varchar2_ntt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

The error returned is:

```
Error(49,6): PL/SQL: ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function
```

Comment: *unable to use the collect function* is not a valid Oracle error message. What exactly does "not work"? What's the error message?

Comment: Is VARCHAR2_NTT declared as a SQL type or a PL/SQL type in a package?

Comment: "Error(49,6): PL/SQL: ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function"...this is the error i get wen I compile the proceudre with the above query. Also the VARCHAR@_NTT is defined as ..."create or replace TYPE varchar2_ntt AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);"

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem in Oracle where the SQL and PL/SQL engine parsers differ and, in this case, PL/SQL won't let you use `distinct` in an aggregated function. See [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1058232381458#11384357177468) AskTom response from 2003 regarding this.

His advice is to use a dynamically opened ref cursor. Other solutions would be to wrap your query with an outer query (like Glenn's answer) or, my preference, turn it into a view and select from that instead. Using dynamic SQL also works in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping it in a subquery?

```
    SELECT companyCode, companyDesc, plantCode, 
           cast(COLLECT(haulierCode) as varchar2_ntt) haulierCode,
           cast(COLLECT(haulierName) as varchar2_ntt) haulierName
    FROM (

    SELECT
    nvl(spicd.COMPANY_CODE,'') companyCode,
    nvl(scc.COMPANY_DESCRIPTION,'') companyDesc,    
    nvl(spicd.PLANT_CODE,'') plantCode,
    nvl(sh.HAULIER_CODE, 'UNKNOWN HAULIER CODE') haulierCode,
    nvl(sh.haulier_name, 'UNKNOWN HAULIER NAME') haulierName
    from
    SAISTB_COMPANY_CODE scc,
    SAISTB_PVE_INDV_CONTACT_DET spicd

    left outer join SAISTB_VENDOR_HAULIER svh on
    svh.COMPANY_CODE = spicd.COMPANY_CODE and
    svh.PLANT_CODE = spicd.PLANT_CODE and
    svh.VENDOR_CODE = spicd.VENDOR_CODE

    left outer join SAISTB_HAULIER sh on
    sh.HAULIER_CODE = svh.HAULIER_CODE

    where
    scc.COMPANY_CODE = spicd.COMPANY_CODE
    and spicd.COMPANY_CODE like <<CompanyCode>>
    and spicd.PLANT_CODE like <<PlantCode>>

    group by
    nvl(spicd.COMPANY_CODE,''),         
    nvl(scc.COMPANY_DESCRIPTION,''),    
    nvl(spicd.PLANT_CODE,''),
    nvl(sh.HAULIER_CODE, 'UNKNOWN HAULIER CODE') haulierCode,
    nvl(sh.haulier_name, 'UNKNOWN HAULIER NAME') haulierName

    )

    GROUP BY companyCode, companyDesc, plantCode
```

The inner group by performs the "distinct" operation.